# Why JavaScript Performs "click" event, when I don't click on the item?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I added `eventListener` on `DOM` object using `JS`, but this listeners triggers, as soon as page is loaded and it doesn't have sense, when I'm clicking on this item.

This is my code, where I'm adding `eventListener` to the item:

```
 let table = document.getElementById('data_table' + deal);
 for (let r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
     table.rows[r].cells[2].addEventListener("click", logThis(this));
 }
```

and my `function` which should be execute on item click, looks like this:

```
 function logThis(me) {
     console.log(me);
 }
```

When browser renders page, clicking is performing itself, without my interference.
Please, if anyone here knows, why it happens, write the answer.

**EDIT**

When I'm clicking, on table `cell`, nothing happens

Comment: You're clearly calling the function: `logThis(this)`.

Comment: @Teemu No, I'm not calling this function anywhere in source code

Comment: You just need to pass the function name inside addEventListener call. No need to invoke it. 
`table.rows[r].cells[2].addEventListener("click", logThis);`

Comment: Wut? I just copy-pasted the invoke in my comment from your example!

Comment: @codeVerine YES! you're right; please, write It in answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding my comment as an aswer here to help other beginners get into this issue.
Here you have mixed both `addEventListener` signature and the way you add `onclick` handlers in HTML.

When you attach an eventListener using JS, you dont have to invoke the function(ie no need to use the parenthesis). So your code will be like this:
`table.rows[r].cells[2].addEventListener("click", logThis);`

When you attach an event handler from HTML you do this: 
`<td onclick="logThis()">Click me</td>` Here you need to pass the string with function invocation.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You need to create a function in the addEventListener and than call your method.

```
table.rows[r].cells[2].addEventListener("click", function () {logThis(this)});

function logThis(me) {
    console.log(me);
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a global event listener on your table with event delegation

```js
document.querySelector('#my-Table').onclick =e=>{
  if ( e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'td') return
  if ( e.target.cellIndex !=2 ) return

  console.clear()
  console.log('=>',  e.target.textContent , ' is clicked !')
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse}
td { border: 1px solid grey; padding: .3em .5em;}
```

```html
<table id="my-Table">
  <tbody>
      <tr><td>aa</td><td>bb</td><td>cc</td><td>dd</td></tr>
      <tr><td>ee</td><td>ff</td><td>gg</td><td>hh</td></tr>
      <tr><td>ii</td><td>jj</td><td>kk</td><td>ll</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p> this get click only on row 2 ( cc / gg / kk ) </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Despite founding of issue, why my code wasn't working, (I was invoking function) I still was not able to add `eventListener` to the `DOM` element. So, I tried to set `attribute` to this element using `JavaScript` and now it works. I'm afraid, that this is not best solution, but It is still kinda way to accomplish my aim.

```
let table = document.getElementById('data_table' + deal);
for (let r = 0, n = table.rows.length; r < n; r++) {
     table.rows[r].cells[2].setAttribute("onclick", "logThis(this)");
}
```